# Expanding QChartView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcharts

A little at lost as to why `QChartView` will expand when put inside of a `QTabWidget`.

Here's a picture of the application when `QChartView` is not expanding (because it's hidden).

[image]

The black portion of the app is `QOpenGLWidget`.

When I click on the chart view, it will gradually increase in size until `QOpenGLWidget` is hidden.

[image]

When `QChartView` is just in a `QVBoxLayout` with `QOpenGLWidget`, then this effect does not occur. It's only when I add `QChartView` inside of the `QTabWidget` that this happens. I'm trying to figure out how to have `QChartView` not expand, and resize the same way other widgets do (such as the `QTextEdit` widget in this example).

Here's the code, which was written as a minimal example to reproduce the effect.

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QChart>
#include <QChartView>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  // Main Window

  QMainWindow main_window;

  main_window.resize(1280, 720);

  main_window.show();

  // Central Widget

  QWidget central_widget(&main_window);

  main_window.setCentralWidget(&central_widget);

  QVBoxLayout layout(&central_widget);

  central_widget.setLayout(&layout);

  // OpenGL Widget

  QOpenGLWidget gl_widget(&central_widget);

  gl_widget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

  layout.addWidget(&gl_widget);

  // Tab Widget

  QTabWidget tab_widget(&central_widget);

  layout.addWidget(&tab_widget);

  // Log

  QTextEdit text_edit(&tab_widget);

  text_edit.setReadOnly(true);

  tab_widget.addTab(&text_edit, "Log");

  // Chart View

  QtCharts::QChartView chart_view(&tab_widget);

  tab_widget.addTab(&chart_view, "Chart");

  return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because the QChartView has the expansion sizePolicy as opposed to the QOpenGLWidget, so when it becomes visible it expands, hiding the other widget. The solution is to set a stretch factor associated with each widget in the layout:

```cpp
layout.addWidget(&gl_widget, 1);
```

```
layout.addWidget(&tab_widget, 1);
```

Comment: This fixed this issue, thank you. The size policy of `QOpenGLWidget` is set to `Expanding` in the code, though, so I'm still not sure why this change was required.

Comment: How do you do this if the QTabWidget is within a QGridLayout? I still get expanding charts with passing Qt::Alignment(1).